# Jquery, ajax, fadeIn, fadeOut

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this function:

```
  function update_page(html){
    $('#pagg').html(html);
}

   $(function(){
    $('#pagg > a').live('click', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
           var link = $(this).attr('href');

       $('.news').fadeOut(2000, function(){                    
          $.ajax({
                 url: link,
                 type: 'get',
                 success: function(html){
                     update_page(html).fadeIn(2000);
                 }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });         
});
```

fadeOut is working, but fadeIn is not working. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: It seems that nothing from above is workin, but if I change first part to: 
function update_page(html){ return $('.news').html(html); } it is working, but it is producing double results ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten using delegate:

```
$(function(){     
    $('#pagg').delegate('a', 'click', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var link = $(this).attr('href');
         $('.news').fadeOut(2000).remove(this);
         $.ajax({
             url: link,
             type: 'get',
             success: function(html){
                 $('#pagg').html(html).find('.news').fadeIn(2000);
             }
         });
     });
     return false; 
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, it  seems that this function is not working. After the click, nothing is being shown.

Comment: I made the assumption that the the .news class was under the #pagg id, if not remove the `.find('.news')` part. Looks like I also have an extra closing tag in there: editing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
function carga_sector(contenedor,url,parametros)
{
    var contenedor="#"+contenedor;
    var url,parametros;
        $(contenedor).html('<div><img src="images/load.gif"/>Cargando...</div>');
        $(contenedor).fadeOut('slow',function()
            {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url:url,
                        type:'post',
                        data:parametros,
                        async:true,
                        success: function(data) 
                                {
                                    $(contenedor).html(data);
                                    $(contenedor).fadeIn('fast');
                                },
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        dataType: "html",
                        global: true,
                        ifModified: false,
                        processData:true
                     }
                );
            }
        )
}

<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
onclick="javascript:carga_sector('div_nombre','pagina.php','&par1=valor1&valor2=valor2')">Envia Datos < /a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
onclick="javascript:carga_sector('div_nombre','pagina.php',$("#form").serialize())">Envia Formulario < /a>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the update_page function to this:

```
function update_page(html){
  return $('#pagg').html(html);
}
```

so that .fadeIn() gets called on a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `update_page` needs to return the jQuery object so it can be chained

```
function update_page(html){
    return $('#pagg').html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update_page() is not a jQuery object.

try:

```
function update_page(html){
    $('#pagg').html(html).fadeIn(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues: one is the chain the other is the call:

```
function update_page(html){
     $('#pagg').html(html).fadeIn(2000);
}
$(function(){
    $('#pagg > a').live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.news').fadeOut(2000, function(){
             $.ajax({ 
                 url: link,
                 type: 'get',
                 success: function(html){
                     update_page(html);
                  }
             });
         });
    return false;
    });
});
```

EDIT: This code does bother me a bit in that IF you are fading from one class of .news to another NEW class, the old one will still BE there and they BOTH will fade back in.

If that is also an issue you may want to remove the old one prior to fade in of the new one...or even prior to the new insertion of new content.

Comment: I change bottom part with: $(function(){
        $('#pagg > a').live('click', function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
               var link = $(this).attr('href');
               
        $('.news').fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).remove();});                    
              $.ajax({
                     url: link,
                     type: 'get',
                     success: function(html){
                         update_page(html).fadeIn(2000);
                     }
                });
            });

Comment: I still think you need to move the fadeIn to the function where it creates the content so that the fadeIn is called on the new jquery object not on the function object.

Comment: It is working, but another problem has appeared. Delete function which is associated with <a> tag is not working after this function is activated.

Comment: $(".delete").click(function() {var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");            
        var string = 'id='+ id ;
        $.ajax({   
            url: "<?php echo site_url('news/delete') ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){commentContainer.slideUp('1500', function() {$(this).remove();});}   
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('.delete').confirm(
    {
        msg: 'You are about to delete this article. Are you sure?<br>',
        buttons: {separator: ' - '}});

Comment: I would add a new question with the markup and this/other code in so it can be evaluated separately and in context.